# Get text content in css after

Tags: html, css

Given this HTML:

```
<span data-title="Attribution">test</span>
```

I can use in CSS `after` to retrieve `data-title`

```
span:after{ content: attr(data-title); }
```

But what I need is the span text content, in the example above `test`, is it possible to get it in CSS `after` ?

Comment: no, not possible. And why you need it in `after` since it's already there?

Comment: I'm trying to add a tooltip, as the text may be too long and I'm truncating it

Comment: so you add the text as attribute .. you use `before` to show truncated text and `after` for the tooltip

Comment: I can't change the HTML, otherwise I would use `title`

Comment: so you need to add all these details in your question to make it accurate and to have a good answer. Actually what you described in the comments is different from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to get the inner text of an html element through CSS. Javascript will have to be used at some point, however, you could for instance use Javascript to set an attribute for your span and use CSS to read that attribute -

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  var mytext = elems[i].innerText;
  elems[i].dataset.trunc = mytext;
}
```

```css
span:before {
  content: attr(data-trunc);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span>Some-Text</span>
<span>More-Text</span>
<span>Other-Text</span>
```